Instancing pillars whose length is controlled by 2 raycasted positions
I am trying to create [any 2d shape, such as an H-Beam or L-beam or cylinder] instanced between these two plane objects. I would like a single vertex to control the instanced pillars' X+Y positions, but have each pillar automatically length-change between the two planes which I have raycasted toward.
I tried to use raycasted hit positions to act as start/end vectors for a curve line which could be given a profile curve, but the curve line node doesn't like the field inputs. This is as far as I can get.
I know it would be significantly easier to simply raycast to one of these planes only, extrude, then boolean the remainder portions, but I specifically want a "smart setup" where the start and end of the cylinder are at the raycasted positions.


Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

If I understand well, the solution is simple, first raycast to the top plane and capture the position, then to the bottom one and create curve line "instance on points" after your realize them just set the endpoints positions to the captured value.
Similar approch you can use if you want to raycast the entire profiles, first raycast the curve profiles converted to "curve to mesh" then extrude with the 0 height and use the top selection for the placement of the upper part.
And if you want to use pure instances just extrude your beams with normalized height equal to 1 and then use the second raycast distance to scale them.




